# Is there a bug in the Civilization 6 "X completed" messages in the City construction view?

Tags: civilization-6

When one of my cities have completed a building and I click the button `CHOOSE PRODUCTION` button, and I can't remember what it was building, I look at the top of the right hand side. It will read something like `TRADER COMPLETED`. But I'm pretty sure that it's always wrong. It seems to be that it's actually showing the previously completed item. Is anyone else experiencing this? I'm just about to submit a bug report (or "support request") to 2K, but I don't imagine it would cause an immediate fix/patch :)

EDIT: I've submitted a bug, with request ID "1914906"

Comment: -1? Does that mean you don't get this, or do you not think it's a valid question for this stackexchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. I don't know of any public place where the Civ team tracks their bugs, but I can confirm that the "X Completed" message may be wrong or missing in certain cases. The wrong message tends to be something that you completed a while back. I *think* this happens frequently when you open a city, dont do anything in the city, then go do something else, then go back to the city.

Comment: I can access the bug here:
http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/requests/1914906?page=1
I have to log in to see it, so it might only be visible to me?

Answer (score -3):

Like he said, it is indeed a bug. It's rather annoying when you have a lot of cities and that you're not sure what you've just completed. For instance, after building an archeological museum I forgot to scroll down and produce an archeologist. It's confusing for late games at marathon - huge map especially.